# Composer add custom vendor library

Tags: composer-php

Guys in my project am using PSR-4 to load modules located in modules directory.
I want to create in vendor my own library and setup autoloader to load all libraries..

my composer.json

```
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir" : "library"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "modules/"
    }
```

Example dir structure:

```
|Root_Dir
|--- Modules
|------Company
|---------TestModule
|-------------Controlers
|--etc...
```

My vendor is named library and there i have many packages instaled like DOctrine, Symfony comps, etc..

I want to add custom my own library in that directory and load in my controllers using namespaces.

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried to simply create a composer package like described in the documentation? https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md

Comment: but i must publish it?

Comment: What have you tried? You have to have the package somewhere you can access it, but it need not be public or on packagist.org.